# How to show Header content on checkout page in magento2

Tags: magento2

How to show Header content on checkout page in magento2?

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Comment: luma theme any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Override checkout_index_index.xml in theme with the below code and header will be displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <!-- <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" /> -->
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: i want to show it in luma theme

Comment: not working in luma theme

Comment: Create a new theme by following the doc : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html and override the xml file like I mentioned.

Comment: i want to dispaly in luma theme not other theme

Comment: Yes. However luma is Magento default theme. It is not recommended to change the core code. So, you need to create a custom theme to override the xml file.

Comment: Not satisfy if we extend luma theme than is it possible to show on default theme

Comment: Exactly. Create a new theme whose parent would be Luma theme.